# How to execute Javascript code from a PHP function?

Tags: php, javascript

Ok, what I'm doing right now is just echoing an script tag. For example:

```
echo '<script>alert("Hello world")</script>';
```

Is this the right way to do this? or is there a better way?

Comment: could you please finally review the answers to this and your previous questions and either accept the most helpful ones or edit your questions to point out why none of the answers solve your question. We took our time to help you, now please take your time to show some appreciation. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot execute JavaScript from PHP. Unless you are using [Server-side JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions), all JavaScript is only ever executed on the client side - in the browser. That means your PHP code only *writes* the JS code onto the page the browser will show later. This page is served from your webserver to the requesting browser and that is where and when the JS code is *executed* then. For PHP, the JS you echo has no meaning. It is just a string like everything else.

Apart from this, yes. This is how you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon said, you cannot *execute* js from php. Only you can is *generate* js code as well as HTML and send it to the browser where it is going to be executed.

as for the better way, you can escape from PHP and write pure DHTML as is:

```
function jsalert() {
?>
<script>alert("Hello world")</script>
<?
}
```

it is considered better for obvious reasons.

Also consider to divide your app into 2 parts: business logic and presentation logic. (D)HTML should be present only in the latter one. A simplest but powerful and widely used example of presentation logic part is as simple as just php file being included into business logic file.
Say, here goes a business logic

```
<? 
$str = "Hello world!";
include "js-tpl-example.php";
?>
```

and a template:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
<script>alert("<?=$str?>")</script>';
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For executing a function I don't think so. But if you deal with more complex objects and serialization you may try `json_encode` instead of manually printing all the objects/arrays out.